# What do the security warnings from cflint mean?

Tags: appsec

I am going to use the open source tool `cflint` but I would like to know what some of the warnings it lists actually mean or what they imply.  The warnings in question are ones relating to security:

> QUERYPARAM_REQ -  SetSql()  statement should use  .addParam()

and

> CFQUERYPARAM_REQ -  cfquery  should use  < cfqueryparam>

Given these warnings, what problem do these indicate with the security of a program?  I understand what fix they are suggesting, but what problem does this cause for security?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like it's asking you to use parameterized SQL queries to prevent [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection). Using parameterized SQL prevents first order SQL injection attacks by treating the input as a parameter, rather than just concatenating strings.  For example, consider the following query :

> "Select * from dbo.Users where Lastname='{value}';"

Assume a malicious user is attempting to input "' or 1=1; --".  Using regular concatenation, this query becomes

> Select * from dbo.Users where Lastname='' or 1=1; --;

and the application will return all rows from the users table.  With parameterized SQL, the query will become

> Select * from dbo.Users where Lastname=''' or 1=1; --';

and will only return rows where the last name matches "' or 1=1; --".

[This stack overflow post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/94560/sql-injection-attacks-how-do-i-test-and-secure-coldfusion-queries) may also have some useful information.